# I wonder if the moderators(some) here have slight knowledge of islam?

Tags: discussion

There are many qood question with down vote. Seriously. And as for answers, many of them are hilarious. And when i stated this fact, my answers got deleted. you kidding me!/

if you have(moderator(s)) any grudge then leave dont bother reading things which bother you. And if you care so much, why dont you down vote those with literary trash answers? Make the good question positive.

That's why Many muslim dont use this site...........

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Prior to making wrong claims based on wrong assumption and prejudice you should first make yourself familiar with the site and the stackexchange model by taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Most of your wrongful convinction would be clarified. We want to answer questions about Islam we are not a typical internet forum! It is easy to leave the burden on a handfull of shoulders and accuse them for whatever, but we are looking for active members wo help us answer real questions and increase the quality of the questions and answers.

Comment: Where are these (down-voted) good questions? You make claims and didn't give any proof or examples of what you pretend!

Answer (score 4):

Stack Exchange sites are community-moderated. That means literally anybody with enough reputation can vote on posts, not only to up/down vote but also to vote to close or delete posts as they see fit. *You* are as much a moderator on this site as anyone else.

I agree that the voting culture here sometimes leaves much to be desired regarding the quality of certain posts, but telling people to "dont bother reading things which bother you" is exactly the wrong solution to this problem: Quality control is an important part of maintaining this site, and ensuring that posts which meet site standards and show knowledge of Islam are upvoted and those which *don't* are downvoted is essential to make sure that the people with the power *to* moderate the site are actually qualified to do so.

Outside of the voting history on any particular user, we simply have no way of determining the expertise of random strangers on the Internet. Many of the people who use this site definitely have more than a "slight knowledge" of Islam, but there are also many that do not. We do not check credentials at the door.

If you really want to make a difference, you need to earn reputation by posting good, clear, focused questions and answers, and using your privileges to curate the site. If a post is downvoted that you feel deserves more attention, you can upvote it yourself, or improve it with constructive edits. If your own posts are downvoted or deleted, learn from your mistakes and improve them, or just do better next time.

Meanwhile, if you don't understand why a question was downvoted, feel free to discuss it on meta; sometimes questions that don't deserve downvotes do get downvoted, but often they're downvoted because of a clear lack of research effort, or due to unaddressed problems with the question that prevent it from getting good answers in the first place. Also note that we are *not* a fatwa site or an advice site, and many posts are downvoted simply because we are in no way qualified to answer them here.